# Suggest any Good mustache document

Tags: javascript, mustache

Suggest me any good mustache doc. Also i want to know in a mushtach loop how do i get the `count or the loop no`. I mean how can i do a `for loop` in mustache.

In the below code i wish to change the id in every loop

```
<script src="http://github.com/janl/mustache.js/raw/master/mustache.js"></script>  
<script>

var data, template, html;

data = {
    name : "Some Tuts+ Sites",
    big: ["Nettuts+", "Psdtuts+", "Mobiletuts+"],
    url : function () {
        return function (text, render) {
            text = render(text);
            var url = text.trim().toLowerCase().split('tuts+')[0] + '.tutsplus.com';
            return '<a href="' + url + '">' + text + '</a>';
        }
    }
};

 template = '<h1> {{name}} </h1><ul> {{#big}}<li id="no"> {{#url}} {{.}} {{/url}} </li> {{/big}}  </ul>';

html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

document.write(html)

</script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: A decent introduction and screen cast is here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-using-the-mustache-template-library/

Comment: Nice docs are here: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/, and here: http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get at the array index in Mustache, Mustache is deliberately simple and wants you to do all the work when you set up your data.

However, you can tweak your data to include the indices:

```
data = {
    //...
    big: [
        { i: 0, v: "Nettuts+" },
        { i: 1, v: "Psdtuts+" },
        { i: 2, v: "Mobiletuts+" }
    ],
    //...
};
```

and then adjust your template to use `{{i}}` in the `id` attributes and `{{v}}` instead of `{{.}}` for the text:

```
template = '<h1> {{name}} </h1><ul> {{#big}}<li id="no-{{i}}"> {{#url}} {{v}} {{/url}} </li> {{/big}}  </ul>';
```

And as an aside, you probably want to include a scheme in your `url`:

```
url : function () {
    return function (text, render) {
        text = render(text);
        var url = text.trim().toLowerCase().split('tuts+')[0] + '.tutsplus.com';
        return '<a href="http://' + url + '">' + text + '</a>';
        //---------------^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SFXGG/

Comment: i wish to ue this with dynamic row creations something like "add new row"

Comment: @Web: I don't know what you mean. If you have an array of strings then you just have to convert it to an array of objects. If you want to add a new `<li>` then you could count how many are already in the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @mu's answer, you could also keep an index in the data object and have the template refer to it and the function increment it. So you wouldn't need to add i to each item.
see demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5vsZ2/